# Ansible set up Rails VPS

Tags: unix, ubuntu, ssh, ansible, vps

I am setting up a VPS using Ansible. Here is my build_server yaml file:

```
---
- hosts: do_server
  vars_files:
    - vars/defaults.yml
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - { role: create-deploy-user, tags: ['create-deploy-user'] }


- hosts: do_server
  vars_files:
    - vars/defaults.yml
  remote_user: "{{ deploy }}"
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    ### Server provisioning roles:
    - { role: linux-prereqs, tags: ['linux-prereqs'] }
    - { role: postgresql, tags: ['postgresql'] }
    - { role: rbenv, tags: ['rbenv'] }
    - { role: ruby, tags: ['ruby'] }
    - { role: nginx-passenger, tags: ['nginx-passenger'] }

    ### Site specific roles:
    - { role: prepare_site, tags: ['prepare_site'] }
```

It goes along file until it gets to the linux-prereqs role. Here I get an error: "Missing become password".

I'm a bit confused by this as I am not setting a password for my "deploy" user and am adding my SSH key to it as part of creating the user so surely I should already be authorised?  My create deploy user task is:

```
- name: create {{ deploy }} user
  user:
    name: "{{ deploy }}"
    comment: "deploy user"
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: authorize my SSH key to access {{ deploy }}
  authorized_key:
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/Users/neil/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    user: "{{ deploy }}"
    state: present

- name: add {{ deploy }} to sudoers
  lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers state=present line='{{ deploy }} ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL'"

- name: create www-data group
  group:
    name: www-data
    state: present
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your deploy user does not have passwordless sudo (`{{ deploy }} ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL'`) so Ansible is being prompted for the user's password as soon as it attempts to do anything that requires privilege escalation. As you haven't provided one either via the CLI or as a variable then Ansible will fail.

To fix this either specify the deploy user's password via the CLI or in variables or alter your sudoers file task to the following:

```
- name: add {{ deploy }} to sudoers
  lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers state=present line='{{ deploy }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'"
```